# Vimeo API list of albums or videos returns 200 but no list. (in react native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, vimeo, vimeo-api

My goal is to fetch a list of albums or list of videos in Vimeo from my Vimeo account where everything is private. I am using React Native and the javascript fetch function...

```
fetch(`https://api.vimeo.com/users/13477675/albums?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>`,{
            method: 'GET',
            page: 1,
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json',
                "Authorization" : "Bearer <TEST_TOKEN>"
            })
        }).then((response)=>{
            console.log('RESPONSE: '+JSON.stringify(response));
        });
```

I get a JSON response where the status code is 200, just like it is suppose to be. However, I do not get a list of albums or videos or anything of the sort. (When I use the Vimeo playground I do get a list of albums or videos as expected and am using the same information there...)

Here is what I get in response:

```
{"type":"default","status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":200,"headers":{"map":{"x-ratelimit-remaining":["95"],"x-ratelimit-limit":["100"],"expires":["Fri, 21 Apr 2028 00:26:23 GMT"],"connection":["keep-alive"],"cache-control":["no-cache, max-age=315360000"],"vary":["Accept,Vimeo-Client-Id,Accept-Encoding"],"content-type":["application/vnd.vimeo.album+json"],"date":["Tue, 24 Apr 2018 00:26:23 GMT"],"content-encoding":["gzip"],"via":["1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish"],"x-cache-hits":["0, 0"],"accept-ranges":["bytes"],"strict-transport-security":["max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload"],"x-cache":["MISS, MISS"],"x-ratelimit-reset":["2018-04-24T00:41:23+00:00"],"x-served-by":["cache-iad2143-IAD, cache-dca17724-DCA"],"age":["0"],"server":["nginx"],"x-timer":["S1524529583.137340,VS0,VE316"],"content-length":["3391"]}},"url":"","_bodyInit":{"listeners":{},"isRNFetchBlobPolyfill":true,"multipartBoundary":null,"_ref":"/Users/jeremyfrancis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E1D3C5D3-5FF7-4C3A-81A4-B6A823F8A7AF/data/Containers/Data/Application/8AA6BEA8-EE15-4E6E-8AE2-A31CC571E19E/Documents/RNFetchBlob-blobs/blob-tb4fwue6s2ls7tjhcl8b","_blobCreated":true,"_closed":false,"cacheName":"blob-tb4fwue6s2ls7tjhcl8b","type":"text/plain","size":86998},"_bodyBlob":{"listeners":{},"isRNFetchBlobPolyfill":true,"multipartBoundary":null,"_ref":"/Users/jeremyfrancis/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E1D3C5D3-5FF7-4C3A-81A4-B6A823F8A7AF/data/Containers/Data/Application/8AA6BEA8-EE15-4E6E-8AE2-A31CC571E19E/Documents/RNFetchBlob-blobs/blob-tb4fwue6s2ls7tjhcl8b","_blobCreated":true,"_closed":false,"cacheName":"blob-tb4fwue6s2ls7tjhcl8b","type":"text/plain","size":86998}}
```

And here is where I am looking in Vimeo Dev API: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/albums

**UPDATE**

I have updated my code to use .json() as follows...

```
fetch(`https://api.vimeo.com/users/13477675/albums?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>`,{
        method: 'GET',
        page: 1,
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json',
            "Authorization" : "Bearer <TEST_TOKEN>"
        })
    }).then(response => response.json()).then((response)=>{
        console.log('RESPONSE: '+JSON.stringify(response));
    }).catch((error)=>{console.log(error.message});
```

This catches an error and prints: "Unable to resolve data for blob: (null)"

Comment: @CertainPerformance console.log(response) prints '[object Object]' so it is not a string.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I missed that the method was `fetch`.

Comment: Just curious, why is your client id passed as a query parameter to the albums url?

Comment: Uhh I don’t know.. I’m new to this. 0.o I am no longer using the client id at all though, I’m just using a test token. I want to avoid the user having to do anything for authentication, I want my private albums and videos displayed right in the app because the user already puts a password in to access the app. I know the documentation says that is for testing only. Do you think it matters much? @Dashron

Comment: No worries :) We love helping newcomers. You don't need to include the client id in the url, in fact I would recommend not including the client id there just to be a little more secure. Your workflow sounds fine, but I can't tell what aspect is for testing only? If you have a moment, can you link to the docs you were referencing? Your tokens should be fine for production use.

Comment: https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/<app_id>#authentication Near the bottom it says "Need an access token for scripts or testing? Generate one here." I have also seen other people say it is only for testing. @Dashron

Comment: Thanks! I'll chat with the team and fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. I realized React Native does not work well with things like this but the react-native-fetch-blob npm package fixes this problem. Here is my new working code:

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET',`https://api.vimeo.com/users/13477675/albums?client_id=${client_id}`,{
        "Authorization" : "Bearer <TOKEN>"
    }).then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    });
```

That's it! I get the correct JSON returned.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of a `fetch` call is a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. It's not the *actual* object you want - it's a *stream* that has to be parsed into an object (or to text, or whatever) before it can be used.

Since you're dealing with JSON, you need to direct the response to parse the JSON into an object:

```
fetch(`https://api.vimeo.com/users/13477675/albums?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>`, {
  method: 'GET',
  page: 1,
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json',
    "Authorization": "Bearer <TEST_TOKEN>"
  })
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseObject => {
    console.log('RESPONSE: ' + JSON.stringify(responseObject));
    console.log(responseObject.type);
  });
```

There's not many useful things you can do with the Response object before you parse it, other than checking its `ok` property.

Comment: That makes more sense thank you. However, In doing that with the response I catch this error: "Unable to resolve data for blob: (null)"

Comment: Are you sure you returned the `response.json()`?

Comment: Yes I did your code exactly. I also tried printing response.json() and it is undefined. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Turns out it's a problem with React Native I have to use react-native-blob. @CertainPerformance